# Rendering 3-D point clouds obtained from depth maps as a 2.5D video

Tags: 3d, mesh, video

Suppose I have code to generate a bunch of frames, each of which is a depth map(I have access to the matrices which represent depth) which in turn is used to generate a point cloud. One frame would look like this:

[image]

In short I have a point cloud corresponding to each frame. How would I generate a video where each point cloud in a frame is meshed together?

Are there frameworks which handle this kind of data? I am assuming OpenGL should help but I am not sure if it can do this.

Comment: http://wisionlab.cs.wisc.edu/project/quanta-burst-photography/ - maybe this paper will be helpful ("Quanta Burst Photography" by Ma et al. 2020)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application, you could use image-based solutions that are much cheaper than meshing a uniformly sampled set of points. For example, you could use the depth map as a [height map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heightmap).

There are many techniques that allow you to render it in an efficient way, the more realistic the more difficult to code as a shader (but not too much). From easiest to harder:

- [height maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heightmap)
- [normal maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping)
- [displacement mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_mapping)
- [parallax mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_mapping)
- geometry shaders to recreate the actual mesh from a set of primitives and the depth map
- and so on.

Comment: I was looking to create something like this https://vimeo.com/125511537. Didn't know how it's done. I kinda assumed the workflow I mentioned in the question and hypothesised that's how it's done.

Comment: As far as you have the depth map, I guess the shadow in that video is rendered with [shadow mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping). The main object may be rendered in many ways. 
The easiest technique (if scanner resolution is not too high) consist on generate a quad per pixel in your depth map and set the axis coordinate according to depth values in the vertexes. If you want to do it in a more efficient way or scanner resolution may vary with time, the quads can be generated by a geometry shader from a more basic mesh.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of algorithms for generating meshes from point clouds. I am going to suggest looking at the libraries [CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tuto_reconstruction.html) and [PCL](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.html), if only because their documentation has excellent references which should give you ideas on where to look in the literature if you need to roll your own.

[Jonathan Shewchuk](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejrs/) also has some more 2.5D-ish algorithms that may suit your needs.